# SQL To Show Data 7 Days After

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have opened a similar thread before but to no success. It did however help me to improve on my code but I still have not reached my goal. What I am trying to do is to display a set of minutes on my website 7 days after a meeting has taken place. The sql statement for this is as follows:

```
i have taken some of Ashley Banks code and inserted into mine without any success. I am not getting any errors but I am also not getting any data to show up. my code is as follows::

    <?php
$id = $_GET['meeting_id'];
$from = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $row['date_update'] . '-7 days' ) ); 

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Meetings LEFT JOIN Minutes ON Meetings.meeting_id = Minutes.meeting_id 

INNER JOIN Rooms ON Meetings.meeting_id = Rooms.meeting_id 

WHERE  Rooms.date >= "' . $from . '" AND Rooms.date <= NOW() AND Minutes.approval = "approved" AND Meetings.meeting_id = "$id"')

or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       echo '<h3>There Arent Any Minutes For This Meeting Yet</h3>';
    } else {

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><br/>" .'Title: '. $info['title']." </td>";
        echo "<td><br/><br/>" .'Subject: '. $info['subject']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><br/><br/>" .'Next Subject: '. $info['next_subject']."</td>";

        echo '<br/><br/><a href="attendees.php?meeting_id=' . $info['meeting_id'] . '" target="_blank">Attendees</a>';
        echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="apologies.php?meeting_id=' . $info['meeting_id'] . '" target="_blank">Apologies</a>';



        }
    }
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";


?>
```

My tables and fields:

Meetings: meeting_id, title, chairman, secretary, tof, occurances, action

Rooms: room_id, room, date (this is in a varchar field, i know its not in the right format but it was made like that), time, meeting_id.

Minutes: minute_id, subject, next_subject, approval, meeting_id

it is not showing any data. it just echo'ing my message which is 'There arent any minutes for this meeting yet'

My datatype for the date field in my Rooms table is date.

any help guys?

Comment: please print the $result and post it

Comment: i have already said, there is no error message. it just echoing that there arent any minutes for this meeting yet. basically it is not picking up any data although there are minutes that is over 7 days old

Comment: I just want the SQL string. echo $result;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use BETWEEN?

```
$enddate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 week"));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Meetings LEFT JOIN Minutes ON Meetings.meeting_id = Minutes.meeting_id INNER JOIN Rooms ON Meetings.meeting_id = Rooms.meeting_id WHERE  Rooms.date BETWEEN '" . $enddate . "' AND '" . date("Y-m-d") . "' AND Minutes.approval = 'approved' AND Meetings.meeting_id = " . $id;
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: it says: Warning: sprintf() [function.sprintf]: Too few arguments in E:\webareas\hj942\CW\meetings\conference\viewminutes.php on line 64

Comment: If you just "SELECT * FROM Rooms WHERE Rooms.date BETWEEN (start) AND (end)" do you get anything back? If you do then the problem is elsewhere with your joins.

Comment: i now have this error message from trying your code above:  Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in E:\webareas\hj942\CW\meetings\conference\viewminutes.php on line 62

Comment: My code isn't perfect and I don't mean for you to copy-paste it. It's just meant to be an example. Try to select anything from Rooms with the between clause. If that works then your joins are the problem. I don't know the structure of your database and its relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has something to do with: "Rooms.date" being a varchar.
Try the following, but note that this will make any use of an index on the Rooms.date field useless.

replace Rooms.date with:

```
STR_TO_DATE(Rooms.date, '%Y-%m-%d %T');
```

Please have a look at: [Mysql String to Date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
You need to replace the format with the format being used in your Rooms.date field.
The example I used assumes a format like: '2010-10-15 12:34:22'

It would be better to Rooms.date to a real datetime data type